# Can't cast a stored procedure parameter?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter, cast

I have several stored procedures that take a date/time input, one of which takes a date only in the form of a `nvarchar` because it utilizes dynamic SQL. When I try to cast the variable going into the stored procedure, I get an error. This doesn't make much sense to me.

I know I can work around it by creating a second set of `nvarchar` variables or casting within the stored procedure, but I'd like some insight on why I can't just cast the variable in-line.

Example.  ***TOP** is a Select statement telling me my NVARCHAR DATE kicks out just fine.

**MID** is where SSMS is throwing the error, **BOTTOM** is where SSMS thinks it's just fine.*

[image: stored procedure wtfman]

Comment: Why are you casting a date as nvarchar then casting back to date? Also stored procedure parameters can't take expressions - only constants and variables. Finally, [don't use `nvarchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length), and never mind why is this a string, why is it `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`?

Comment: 1. In sprocs called before this one I am using datetime, in this one I only want the date.  2. I'm not, the first is a `select`, not a `set`  3. OK, that explains it.  4. Will do.  5. Because the sproc uses dynamic SQL, as stated in the question.

Comment: Dynamic SQL (or date only) are terrible excuses for converting a date to a string. Your dynamic SQL should still be **safely** parameterizing a date variable through `sp_executesql`, not concatenating and double-single-quoting some date that has been changed to a string.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stored procedure parameters can only accept literals, constants or variables as parameters. It can't take expressions of any kind.

You can say:

```
EXEC dbo.myprocedure @foo = 'bar';
```

But you can't say:

```
EXEC dbo.myprocedure @foo = 'b' + 'ar';
```

You should not be converting a date to a string and then back to a date again. Your dynamic SQL can easily take a date parameter, parameterized safely (you may want to read up on "SQL injection"), and not have to worry about ugly string concatenation. Here is an example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo
  @dt DATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
  SET @sql = N'SELECT DATEPART(DAY, @dt);';
  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@dt DATE', @dt;
END
GO

DECLARE @fromDay DATETIME = '20010914 03:45';
DECLARE @dt DATE = @fromDay; -- or just declare @fromDay as DATE in the first place;
EXEC dbo.foo;
```

Results:

```
----
14
```